# Using namespace std

Tags: c++

Я только начинаю вникать в C++. В разных источниках (да даже и разные товарищи) советуют иногда прямо противоположные вещи, а именно:

- лучше всегда подключать пространство имен полностью (`using namespace std;`),
- лучше всегда подключать только те имена, которые реально используются (`using std::string;`).

Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от конкретной ситуации. Если только начинаешь учить, не заморачивайся на этом. Пока всегда включай std полностью. Сосредоточься на более важных вещах.

Answer (score 1):

Сильно большого значения не имеет, просто пустой перфекционизм, лучше сосредоточиться на реально значимых вопросах. По сути - если используешь много каких классов из неймспейса, то объявлять каждый отдельно, очевидно, геморройно, и не дает никаких особых преимуществ.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую `using namespace` внутри функций, когда полные квалификации могут сильно усложнить читаемость кода.

```
void а()
{
  using namespace std;
  for_each(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я лично предпочитаю либо использовать `using namespace std;` либо явно в коде писать `std::string` или `std::cout` (так я обычно и делаю), но уж точно не буду использовать `using std::string;`.

Если проект достаточно большой, то прописывать явно каждый тип - это будет жуть. А если ещё найдется пара библиотек с одинаковыми именами, то тут будет полный ужас. По каждому типу нужно будет помнить, к какой именно библиотеке она принадлежит.